# Is the Devil William?

Tags: the-witch

In the closing scenes of [The Witch](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4263482/), Thomasin takes covenant with Black Philip and converses with what is assumed to be the Devil, or perhaps Mammon.

Although largely shrouded in darkness, the figure moves through the candlelight for the briefest of moments. It's fleeting, but the figure bears a resemblance to William, Thomasin's father.

Is this the case, and is the devil portrayed by the actor Ralph Ineson?

Answer (score 2):

According to [the Wikipedia page for *The Witch*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Witch_%282015_film%29), an actor named Wahab Chaudhry played Black Phillip. It is not made clear if he only voices the character or if he also plays the character physically, but he does not look dissimilar to what little we see of Black Phillip's human form in the film.